# Basic OOP - 'str' object has no attribute 'age'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to do some basic OOP commands, this code works when I directly put in the attribute name, but not when I try to get it from a user input

```
print('Hello, welcome')

class ManCity:

    def __init__(self, name, age, position):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.position = position

    def getName(self):
        print(self.name)

    def getAge(self):
        print(self.age)

    def getPosition(self):
        print(self.position)


aguero = ManCity('Sergio Aguero', 32, 'Striker')
sterling = ManCity('Raheem Sterling', 27, 'Winger')
jesus = ManCity('Gabriel Jesus', 24,'Striker')
dias = ManCity('Ruben Dias', 29, 'Centre Back')
stones = ManCity('John Stones', 26, 'Centre Back')
ederson = ManCity('Ederson', 29,'GoalKeeper')

chosenName = input(str('Choose Player'))
ManCity.getAge(chosenName)
```

Comment: The argument to `ManCity.getAge()` has to be a `ManCity` instance. `chosenName` is a string.

Comment: If you're trying to type a variable name, that won't work. `input()` doesn't evaluate what you type as a variable, it's just a literal string.

Comment: `ManCity.getAge(chosenName)` is wrong. Why are you passing `chosenName` to `.getAge`?

Comment: If you want to be able to look up a `ManCity` by name, create a dictionary that maps from names to instances. Or you could put all of them in a list, and search it by any attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `chosenName` for each instance like

```py
class ManCity:

    def __init__(self, name, age, position):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.position = position

    def getName(self):
        print(self.name)

    def getAge(self):
        print(self.age)

    def getPosition(self):
        print(self.position)


aguero = ManCity('Sergio Aguero', 32, 'Striker')
sterling = ManCity('Raheem Sterling', 27, 'Winger')
jesus = ManCity('Gabriel Jesus', 24,'Striker')
dias = ManCity('Ruben Dias', 29, 'Centre Back')
stones = ManCity('John Stones', 26, 'Centre Back')
ederson = ManCity('Ederson', 29,'GoalKeeper')

chosenName = input(str('Choose Player'))
# You can iterate over the created objects
for e in [aguero, sterling, jesus, dias, stones, ederson]:
    # for each object you will check if the name is same or not
    if(e.name == chosenName):
        print(e.getAge())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's my first day trying to learn OOP but that makes so much more sense now!

Comment: @AliAltaraif great! all the best. But don't forget to accept the answer so that it won't pop up again :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar suggested, you could create a dictionary that maps from names to instances. This would make looking up the corresponding instance very fast, as well as checking to see it the name was in the dictionary.

Here's an example of doing that. The dictionary is named `players`. Note it maps *lowercase* versions of the players last name to each `Player` instance (and converts the user's input to lowercase before processing it).

```
print('Hello, welcome')

class ManCity:
    def __init__(self, name, age, position):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.position = position

    def getName(self):
        print(self.name)

    def getAge(self):
        print(self.age)

    def getPosition(self):
        print(self.position)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.name!r}, {self.age}, {self.position})'


# Create dictionary mapping players to their lowercase last name.
players = {}
for player in (ManCity('Sergio Aguero', 32, 'Striker'),
               ManCity('Raheem Sterling', 27, 'Winger'),
               ManCity('Gabriel Jesus', 24,'Striker'),
               ManCity('Ruben Dias', 29, 'Centre Back'),
               ManCity('John Stones', 26, 'Centre Back'),
               ManCity('Ederson', 29, 'GoalKeeper')):
    players[ player.name.split()[-1].lower() ] = player

while True:
    chosenName = input('Choose Player: ').lower()
    if chosenName.strip() == '':
        break  # Quit loop.
    if chosenName in players:
        print('Player info:', players[chosenName])
    else:
        print('Unknown name, try again')
```

Usage Sample:

```
Hello, welcome
Choose Player: Ederson
Player info: ManCity('Ederson', 29, GoalKeeper)
Choose Player: dias
Player info: ManCity('Ruben Dias', 29, Centre Back)
Choose Player:
```